# I cannot extend my partition into unallocated space

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I have a dual booted Windows with Ubuntu.
I want to extend my Storage of `/dev/nvme0n1p5` (my Ubuntu partition) into the unallocated space with GParted.
I cannot seem to be able to extend into the empty space
( I also tried from Windows Disk Management)

[image: Screenshot of GParted]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: Little key icons show mounted partitions. You cannot edit mounted partitions, so have to use Ubuntu live installer which has gparted or use a gparted ISO based live flash drive. Since you have a fair amount of data, do not interrupt a move. You have to move left & then expand right. If you interrupt move, you lose all data, so have good backups. And alternative is to create a new partition make it /home & move /home into it. To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key icons beside 2 of your partitions indicates that they're "locked". Notice that they're `mount`ed (on `/` and `/boot/efi`).

To avoid destroying the partition table of the `/dev/nvme0n1` "disk", you cannot edit the partition table while any of its partitions is mounted.

To edit the partition table, boot a Live USB and run `gparted` from there . You cam easily find a Gparted Live USB on the internet.

If your disk is MBR, rather than GPT, you might have to shrink the primary partition (shrink `/dev/nvme0n1p4` first).

Comment: And please please back up before you do it - you’re moving then extending your partition - there’s always a risk of losing everything! Back up the partitions you’re not hoping to change too.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I installed gparted ISO Live and booted from a USB and then resized the partition just fine.